# Why after "freezing" the document.body object, I can modify its properties?

Tags: javascript

### [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze#description)

> Values cannot be changed for data properties. Accessor properties (getters and setters) work the same (and still give the illusion that you are changing the value). Note that values that are objects can still be modified, unless they are also frozen. As an object, an array can be frozen whereafter its elements cannot be altered. No elements can be added or removed from it as well.

```js
'use strict'

document.body.innerHTML = "Hello#1";
var frozen = Object.freeze(document.body);

document.body = frozen;
console.log("Same frozen body (First):", document.body === frozen)
console.log(document.body['innerHTML']);

// Why I can modify this property?
document.body.innerHTML = "Hello#2";

console.log("Same frozen body (Second):", document.body === frozen);
console.log(document.body['innerHTML']);
```

This code snippet is using `getter` and `setter` (This approach fails)

```js
'use strict'

var myObj = {
  a: "Ele#1",
  get innerHTML() {
    return this.a;
  }, 
  set innerHTML(html) {
    this.a = html;
  }
}

myObj = Object.freeze(myObj);
myObj.innerHTML = "Ele";

console.log(myObj);
```

Why after "freezing" the body object, I can modify its properties? for example, `innerHTML`?

***Probably I have a lack of information, I don't know!***

Comment: The second snippet doesn’t do the same thing. You can’t modify the `a` property on `myObj`. Assigning to `document.body.innerHTML` doesn’t necessarily change any property of `document.body`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Accessor properties (getters and setters) work the same (and still give the illusion that you are changing the value).

`innerHTML` is indeed an accessor property as you can see below, and [in the specification](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#dom-element-innerhtml):

```js
function getPropertyDescriptor(object, property) {
  while (typeof object === 'object' && object !== null) {
    const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, property)
    if (descriptor) {
      return descriptor
    }
    
    object = Object.getPrototypeOf(object)
  }
}

const desc = getPropertyDescriptor(document.body, 'innerHTML')

console.log(desc)
```

Modifying your simplified example to use a [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) instead of a property, you can make it work:

```js
'use strict'

const Element = (() => {
  const weakPrivate = new WeakMap()
  
  return class Element {
    constructor () {
      weakPrivate.set(this, { innerHTML: 'initial' })
    }
    
    get innerHTML () {
      return weakPrivate.get(this).innerHTML
    }
    
    set innerHTML (value) {
      return weakPrivate.get(this).innerHTML = value
    }
  }
})()

let object = new Element()

Object.freeze(object)
console.log(object.innerHTML)
object.innerHTML = 'new value'
console.log(object.innerHTML)
```

Answer (score 3):

`innerHTML` is an accessor property. If you debug `document.body` to the console and drill down the prototype chain, you can see it's defined in `Element` as `get innerHTML()` and `set innerHTML()`.

Here's a barebones example of how you can accomplish the same:

```
var myObj = (function() {
    var html = null;

    return {
        get innerHTML() { return html; },
        set innerHTML(value) { html = value; }
    };
})();
```

Comment: But, why creating my own object fails?  See the updated question

Comment: @Ele your own object fails because the setter attempts to modify a non accessor property of your object which is frozen...

Comment: `innerHTML` is implemented differently from what you wrote in your example (probably with some "cheating", i.e. native browser code involved), that's why it can still function after you froze it.

Comment: @Ele I'm going to update my answer and give an example that _does_ work.